# Calling an Interface function from multiple different implementing classes c++

Tags: c++

Hi I am trying to implement an interface in C++. I want to be able to call a function from a class that could be implemented by various different classes. The approach I have tried fails since I cannot call the function with a pointer to the interface (abstract class). Here is the basic gist of the code I have tried:

Interface class:

```
class InterfaceClass{
    virtual void handle() = 0;
};
```

Calling class:

```
CallingClass::CallingClass(InterfaceClass * owner){
    this->owner = owner;
}

void CallingClass::doStuff(){
    owner->handle();
}
```

Implementing classes:

```
class Class1 : public InterfaceClass {
    public:
      Class1();
      void handle();
}

class Class2 : public InterfaceClass {
    public:
      Class2();
      void handle();
}
```

each of the `handle()` functions in the implementing classes just prints out the class name. Each implementing class contains an object of the CallingClass which calls `doStuff` in a separate timer thread. I am trying to keep it so that the CallingClass doesnt need to know anything about the classes that implement the `handle()` function.

It fails since I cannot call the function of an abstract class. I expected this but cant figure a way around it. Any advise would be much appreciated! Let me know if any more information is needed.

Thanks

Comment: "since I cannot call the function with a pointer to the interface (abstract class)." You can. Your problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: `handle()` is a private member of `InterfaceClass` and cannot be called from `CallingClass` unless that's a friend class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were missing the public: keyword in the Interface class. 
you need to remember that C++ class are by default private, so you should add public where it is needed.

this is a working example for you:

```
class InterfaceClass {
public:
    virtual void handle() = 0;
};
class Calling{
public:
    Calling(InterfaceClass * owner) {
        this->owner = owner;
    }
    void doStuff() {
        owner->handle();
    }
    ~Calling() { delete owner; }
private :
    InterfaceClass* owner;
};

class Class1 : public InterfaceClass {
public:
    void handle() override
    {
        std::cout << "Class1"<<std::endl;
    }
};

class Class2 : public InterfaceClass {
public:
    void handle()
    {
        std::cout << "Class2" << std::endl;;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Calling c1(new Class1());
    c1.doStuff();
    Calling c2(new Class2());
    c2.doStuff();
}
```

Comment: Yep, I missed the public keyword. Thanks!